# Fast private computation of dot product

Tags: cr.crypto-security, privacy

Consider two paranoid parties Alice and Bob. Say Alice owns a secret vector $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in \mathbb R^n$ and Bob owns a secret vector $y=(y_1,\ldots,y_n) \in \mathbb R^n$.

> **Question.** How can both parties compute the dot product $x\cdot y$ in time $\mathcal O(n)$ without leaking their respective secrets ?

Comment: Do you need the exact value, or does some approximation suffice? It's worth mentioning that there's a (randomized) communication complexity lower bound of $\Omega(n)$ to compute the inner product (mod 2), so there is "not much slack" to work with compared to the best (non-private) protocol one can use.

Comment: Also, do you care about leaking their secrets to an evesdropper, or also to eachother?

Comment: I'm worried about leaking secrets to each other. You may assume that the communications are otherwise secure (no 3 parties). Also concerning accuracy, I'm realy only interested in testing whether $x^\top y \ge b$ (for some threshold $b \in \mathbb R$ which is known only to Alice).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume you are in the honest-but-curious model.  You can't represent real numbers in finite space, so I will assume all values are represented in fixed-point arithmetic, to $d$ bits of precision; thus $x$ is represented as $x = x'/2^d$ where $x'$ is an integer.  Then $x \cdot y = x' \cdot y' / 2^{2d}$, so the problem is equivalent to computing $x \cdot y$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}^n$.  Here is a scheme for that.

Pick a sufficiently large prime, and let $E$ denote a public-key encryption algorithm that is additively homomorphic modulo $p$.  Alice generates a public/private keypair for $E$, and computes $E(x_i)$ for each $i$.  She sends these to Bob, along with the public key she generated.  Bob computes $E(x_i y_i)$ for each $i$, using the homomorphic properties of $E$, and from them, computes $E(\sum_i x_i  y_i) = E(x \cdot y)$, again using the homomorphic properties of $E$.  Bob sends $E(x \cdot y)$ to Alice.  Alice decrypts, and shares the result with Bob.

Note that if $E$ is additively homomorphic, given $E(x)$ you can compute $E(2x) = E(x+x)$.  Therefore, given $E(x)$ and an integer $y$ you can compute $E(xy)$, using a double-and-add algorithm (analogous to [square-and-multiply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)).

Comment: Yep, indeed I was about to add a comment to you previous answer saying that things could be remedied via FPA, but you deleted it just in time :)

Comment: BTW, do you think the problem is much simplified If but parties are only interested in securely testing whether $x^\top y \ge b$ (where $b$ is a threshold only known to Alice) ? That's if they don't really care about the actual value of $x^\top y$ beyond the fact that it is positive or not.

Comment: @dohmatob it depends on how much "slack" you allow. For example, if you're OK with the computation failing sometimes (say returning YES when $x^ty\geq (1+\epsilon)b$ for $\epsilon >0$, "NO" when $x^ty<b$, and some indeterminate answer in the "middle region"), I suspect you can apply dimensionality reduction techniques to get a decently-sized speedup (the Johnson-Lindenstrauss lemma is the relevant thing to look up, but it is for a *slightly* different problem.)